# how to make a grey warehouse exterior interesting

Tags: technique, architecture, real-estate

Carrying on from my recent question on how to get a decent interior shot, now i need to do the outside.

I am required to photograph the outside of a grey manufacturing warehouse. 
It is new (ish) so nice and clean, however its mighty dull!

I want to deliver something with a bit of wow factor, rather than a grey box with windows.

(someone else took this!)

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's pretty dull isn't it. How about a night shot with a long exposure to get some contrast and glow? Might need to make sure that their logo is illuminated.

Other than that maybe a sunrise/sunset shot is an option if the building faces the correct way or wait for some exciting weather to liven it up.

Alternatively some 'action' shots with employees doing their thing or close ups of building details or odd angles montaged on top of a long shot like the above.

Addendum: As per the interior question adding some people into the shot would provide for some scale and show off the size of the building.

Addendum 2: make sure when shooting that you get the horizon level! The photo above is at a bit of an angle and it makes the building look off kilter

Comment: +1 for night-time; contrast, glow and/or illumination could be helped with some [light painting](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10826/painting-with-light-photography-locations-and-techniques). The other ideas also sound interesting.

Comment: +1 for sunset/sunrise shot, might have walking people with slightly low speed to make them a little blurry / in action. You can also try HDR photos to bring a different effect, pretty trendy this days.

Answer (score 7):

I'm fairly new, but I would try to find an angle that makes the building look really big, like from a low angle and make sure you get something in for perspective, like the boss standing in front. I would try for a time when the sun isn't shining on that spot as it looks a little weird to me. Maybe you if you can get it at the tip at the end of the building it might look more interesting. Or maybe you can get the sun to be at the corner of the picture; I think it just looks awkward in its current position on the building. I'd also move the car, it's distracting.

Again, new to the game, but that's where I would look. I won't be surprised if someone tells me I'm all wrong though.

Comment: Hi @tenmiles, don't worry about being new to the game. There's a place for everybody, be it a *professional, enthusiast or simply an amateur photographer*. I suppose that the car was present in the previous shot, not by the OP, and I agree that it would definitely be better without it.

Comment: +1 -- Dude's (or Dudette's, as the case may be) right. Shooting it as if it were a classic car is pretty much the way to go -- size is everything. I'd also try to get the full length of both visible sides of the building into the picture if possible, since the scope of the place is part of the hook, and cutting off the side just because it (likely) has no interesting architectural features can leave the viewer with a façade that looks like an industrial strip mall. Making it the short side of a front-three-quarters view and letting perspective make it vanish might be more impressive.

Comment: Agree on moving the car, and also that container and porta-potty(?) at the far left. If that's not possible, you may need to employ some photo-editing to get rid of them, because they just make the whole place look messy. The landscaping at the right looks nice, maybe try to include more of that?

Answer (score 4):

The problem with the kind of surface is that the sun will always be reflect on it making the photo dull. I would wait for a better weather preferably cloudy weather where there's light but no sun and you can use warm white balance and saturate your photo a little bit to give warmth to it.

Also try to wait for an action in the sky which happens usually if it's windy. Using a polarizing filter is good to richen the colors.

In addition, look for another angle. If you can find one with greens around it, then try to frame the greens with the building.

As Clara mentioned in her comment, shooting this at night is a good idea. You should try it> However, you'll need a huge light source (perhaps with huge deflector). I however,  think that light painting is tricky because you have to be careful not to point the light to the building surface in a way that reflects it in your camera cause it will be the same problem as the sun reflections.

Try to get further away and use an ultra wide angle lens or fish eye lens.

I find the car in front of the building is distracting. Aim for a time where no cars surround the building.

Try to shoot at sunset or sunrise and look for an angle where the sun is looking at the side of the building so that it illuminates the building face but the rays aren't reflected on its surface. Just be careful not angle yourself with the sun is behind the building cause it will dim the building.

If you want a dramatic photo then shoot [HDR](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7623/what-is-hdr-photography)